# Post to chatter with hyperlink in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, chatter, leads

When new Lead is created I would like to post on chatter group with clickable first and last name of lead, which would redirect user to record page.

Here is what i tried:

1. I tried to mention @[Lead].Id but it crashes Process Builder.
2. I tried formula field `HYPERLINK("/"+Id, 'FirstName')`
   But it returns me this:
   [image]

So is there any other solution for this?
Greetings, Bartek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You cannot mention Lead, you can only mention Users or chatter group.
2. Hyper-Link Dont work in Chatter Mesages via process builder.

You can handle this in a different way, You can change your process builder's **Post to Chatter** to post on "**This Record**".
And then in the chatter body you can mention the chatter group.

[image: Post to chatter on Lead]

Voila, done.. Once lead is created this is the perfect chatter message you need... Visible on Lead as well on Chatter group and all links clickable.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to implement a solution for this, but it's a bit long to post it here in fullness. The bottom line is that I added some additional functionality to Salesforce `ConnectApiHelper` class to support linking to records using the new *Summer '18* class `ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput`. With this change you can now create hyperlinks simply by putting the record ID between the curly brackets likes so:

```
Hi {SOME_USER_ID}, your Opportunity {SOME_OPPORTUNITY_ID} has been updated.
```

I also implemented an `InvocableMethod` so that you can call it from `Process Builder` or `Flow`. The end result was that now I can create Chatter Posts like the one below directly from `Process Builder`:

[image]

You can find the code you need at [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/smukov/ConnectApiHelper), and the detailed instructions on how to use it [here at my blog post](http://smukov.github.io/blog/2018/08/11/Post-to-Chatter-from-Process-Builder-with-hyperlinks-to-records/).